# Move ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] (of mat-table) to another file in Angular

Tags: angular, mat-table

I am building a table using **Material Design styled data-table** for Angular ([doc](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)) and I would like to **transfer the data:**

```
    const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
      {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
      {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
      {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
      {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
      {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
      {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
      {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
      {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
      {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
      {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
    ];
```

**to a separate file**. I enter the data manually (*with Excel but it is not the point*) and often need to change it and for each change I have to compile the entire application.

It would be great if I could just paste the new data file onto the server.

I tried to create a new `.json` file, import it into `app.component.ts` but this caused a lot of errors and let it go.

You can check my beta [here](https://middlers.pl/kredytujem/).

Comment: You mean you want to send data to server on change of data inside table??

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to change manually one file with database.

Comment: we still didnt get what you exactly want to achieve

Comment: Now this database is inside app.component.ts. So when I want to e.g. change some value in this database PeriodicElement[] , I must change it in app.component.ts in Visual Studio Code, then build app and upload all files from >dist> folder to web server. So it would be great, if app.compnent.ts could import this data from separate file that I will upload to web server next to it. And when I change something in database, I would just swap database file on server, instead building app all over again.

Comment: "database" inside my app.component.ts is not "database" its "data" actually.So store data in file in server and do http get , after fetching the file iterate and read through it and set the data in the table accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally dit it!
First created service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://ohipo.pl/assets/oferty.json');
  }
}
```

then get downloaded data in app.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
        this.users = users;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        console.log("users: " + users);
        console.log("dataSource1" + this.dataSource);
      });
```

Worth to mention, that this StackBlitz project helped me a lot:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-modal?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

To achieve above thing,

Create a service - table.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TableDataService{
  public getTableData(){
     this.http.get<any>("your file in server -url");
  }
}
```

Now in your component

```
import { TableDataService} from 'table.service';
datasource;
constructor(private tableService:TableDataService){}

ngOnInit(){
this.tableService.getTableData.subscribe(res=>{
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(res);
});
}
```

in HTML:

So the table will show only if data is loaded

```
<mat-table #table *ngIf="dataSource" [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

These links will help you

https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: what type of file should I store the data in on server? (I mean file extension)

Comment: You can either send that data from the database through api or store in a .json file in server and let front end call for the jsonfile.

Comment: *ngIf="dataSource" breaks sorting. Without using it works just fine.